# Django query single underscore behaving like double underscore?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I made a typo in my code recently and noticed that I got the same behavior, so I was wondering what the difference between single and double underscores are in django queries.

```
>>> underscore = MyModel.objects.filter(foreign_key_id=var)
>>> double_underscore =  MyModel.objects.filter(foreign_key__id=var)
>>> underscore == double_underscore
False
>>> list(underscore) == list(double_underscore)
True
```

I'm not sure what equality method is being used to compare the querysets, but when I convert to python lists I find exactly the same elements contained within. Does anyone have some insight into what's going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those two fields just happen to both exist.

`foreign_key_id` is an automatically created column on the `MyModel` object, whereas `foreign_key__id` is the ID on the foreign key table itself.

These values would both be the same..

```
MyModel1.foreign_key_id == 5  # this is stored on the model
                              # and does not require a lookup.
MyModel1.foreign_key.id == 5  # this is stored on the target table
                              # and requires a DB hit.
```

Comment: How does this effect objects.filter calls? My guess is that __id would have the database handle filtering with a join, whereas _id would return all of the objects in the MyModel table and do the filtering within django. Or do they both filter within the database, but __id touches two tables and _id touches just the one?

Comment: @blackfedora you have tools to view SQL queries

Comment: Thanks, checking with .query it looks like the same mysql queries are generated either way.

Answer (score 1):

`foreign_key_id` is a (hidden) field name of `MyModel`, `foreign_key__id` is a reference to a field on whatever model the `foreign_key` field references. In other words, it is a specific detail of foreign key fields.

Answer (score 1):

From my observations, Django is smart enough to not do a join with the ForeignKey if only filtering or fetching `foreign_key__id`. You can test this with:

```py
>>> print(MyModel.objects.filter(foreign_key_id=var).query)
>>> print(MyModel.objects.filter(foreign_key__id=var).query)
```

Since `underscore` and `double_underscore` are separate objects in memory, I believe this is why `underscore == double_underscore` returns False.